# Check beanstalkd! using udokmeci yii2 beanstalk extension

Tags: php, yii, yii2, beanstalkd

I've been getting this error for days not with no solution in sight. When i run ./yii worker command, I keep getting the error. Code works fine on my local and production environment but I keep getting the error on staging. I made sure beanstalkd is running fine on the environment.
Found that this error is thrown in BeanstalkController line 271 when this condition `$bean = Yii::$app->beanstalk->watch($tube);` is false.

Comment: please check you config ?

Comment: Yes I have. the same code works perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: So it turned out to be the config. Had to put "127.0.0.1" as the beanstalkd host rather than the IP of the staging server. Issue resolved